# How to retrieve data from default rails :data hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I have something like this (basic dropdown-menu):

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <% @sidebar_categories.each do |category| %>
     <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#howtoFormModal">
       <%= link_to category.title, "#", :data => { :id => category.id } %>
     </li>
    <% end %>
 </ul>
```

And I have a form which is inside a modal

```html
<%= simple_form_for @howto, url: category_howtos_path(@category) do |f| %>
  #whatever here...
<% end %>
```

and I would like get the id that I passed previously in the default rail :data hash and put the id inside the form url category_howtos_path(id will go here)

How can I do that please ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve but maybe you can use querystrings, The [docs on link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) has examples of how you can do so.

So in your example something like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <% @sidebar_categories.each do |category| %>
     <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#howtoFormModal">
       <%= link_to category.title, some_path(id: category.id) %>
     </li>
    <% end %>
 </ul>
 # Which has an output like this

<a href="/some-path?id=1">Category Title</a>
```

then...

```
<%= simple_form_for @howto, url: category_howtos_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
  #whatever here...
<% end %>
```

**Edit**

By attributes on the `li` in the first snippet you want to toggle a modal on click, then have the id of the toggled modal in the `simple_form_for` URL param. The Problem is the `category_howtos_path` has been evaluated before page load in ruby. So if you want to change that URL you may want to use javascript. So maybe load the modal in javascript and have an event callback.

**EDIT with JS snippet**

> Yeah, I tried already but maybe I did it the wrong way.
>
> ```
>  $('#howtoFormModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
>
>       //but I think that the JS will give a lot due to the rails loop 
>       var categoryId = $("#li-id").data('id')
>
>       // just to show the id on the modal
>       $('#howtoFormModalLabel').val(categoryId); 
>  });
> ```

You'll want to get the element's id that you have clicked on so

```
 $('#howtoFormModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

  // The categoryId from here needs to be from the clicked on element 
  var categoryId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id')

  // just to show the id on the modal
  $('#howtoFormModalLabel').val(categoryId);
```

});

Comment: This is how it used to be because before it was a form on a different page. But now the is inside a modal so there is no need to go on a different page anymore. thank for your suggestion

Comment: If you update your question with your js code I maybe able to help?

Comment: I've updated my answer with your js edit. `e.relatedTarget` is the element that represents the `li` you have clicked on. that should get you the data attribute.

Comment: it doesn't work. So from here either I mistyped something (I'm sure you know what I'm talking about as a programmer XD) or I used the wrong event on the bootstrap modal but there are only 2 (show.bs.modal and shown.bs.modal).  You helped me see where my problem was : get the elmt I have clicked on so thank you. I'm gonna try something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903992/jquery-determining-which-link-was-clicked and adapt it.