# JQuery Expand Nested Accordion Menu by URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, menu, accordion

i am having the following Problem.
I implemented a nested accordion Menu JQuery script on my Website.
What i need to do now is that the accordion Menu sub categories expand based on an URL.

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w6fa87ov/

You will find that i set the Menu item "Test_2" within "Sub Category 1.2" on active. 
When the user enters the corresponding URL i.e. "/myurl/Test_2" then the Accordion Menu should open the item "Sub Category 1.2" by default.

Iam not a JQuery programmer and i dont know how to do this in JQuery.
My noob consideration was something like:
- If i find an active element within the menu i "click" the corresponding element which should expand it

Thanks in advance, best regards Burnie

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="nestedAccordion">
        <h5 id="id_element_TopKat_Food">First Top Category</h5>
        <div id="container2">
            <h6 id="id_element_Sub1Kat">Sub Category 1.1</h6>
            <div id="container3">
                    <a class="accordionSubKategorie" href="/myurl/Test_0" style="text-decoration:none;">  
                        <h7 id="id_element_Sub2Kat" class="Sub2Kat"> Test_0</h7>
                    </a>
            </div>

            <h6 id="id_element_Sub1Kat">Sub Category 1.2</h6>
            <div id="container3">
                <a class="accordionSubKategorie" href="/myurl/Test_1" style="text-decoration:none;">  
                    <h7 id="id_element_Sub2Kat" class="Sub2Kat"> Test_1</h7>
                </a>
                <a class="accordionSubKategorie" href="/myurl/Test_2" style="text-decoration:none;">   
                    <h7 id="id_element_Sub2Kat" class="Sub2Kat active"> Test_2</h7>
                </a>
                <a class="accordionSubKategorie" href="/myurl/Test_3" style="text-decoration:none;">    
                    <h7 id="id_element_Sub2Kat" class="Sub2Kat"> Test_4</h7>
                </a>   
            </div>
        </div>

        <h5 id="id_element_TopKat_Non-Food">Second Top Category</h5>
        <div id="container2"> 
            <h6 id="id_element_Sub1Kat">Sub Category 2.1</h6>
            <div id="container3">
                <a class="accordionSubKategorie" href="/myurl/Test_4" style="text-decoration:none;">  
                        <h7 id="id_element_Sub2Kat" class="Sub2Kat"> Test_4</h7>
                </a>
            </div>     
        </div> 
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
  var parentDivs = $('#nestedAccordion div');
  var childDivs = $('#nestedAccordion h6').siblings('div');

  $('#nestedAccordion h5').click(function() {
    parentDivs.slideUp();
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    } else {
      $(this).next().slideUp();
    }
  });

  childDivs.slideUp();
  $('#nestedAccordion h6').click(function() {
    childDivs.slideUp();
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    } else {
      $(this).next().slideUp();
    }
  });
```

CSS:

```
    h5 {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #6EB90A;
    color: #fefefe;
    padding: .75em;
    border-radius: 0.15em;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

h5:hover {
  background: #5c8a1c;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

h6 {
    margin-top:-3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #476767;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(71,103,103,1);
    color: #476767;
    padding: .25em;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

h6:hover {
  background: #476767;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

h7.Sub2Kat {

    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: #476767;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: .1em;
    padding-left: 1.8em;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

h7.Sub2Kat:hover {
  background: #6EB90A;
  color: white;
}

h7.Sub2Kat.active {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    padding-left: 1.2em;
}

.Sub2Katactive {
    font-size:0.9em;
}

h7.Sub2Kat.active {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    padding-left: 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved my Prolbem.
Within my Django code which i use to construct the Template i give a specific Class to hasActive or hasPassive which refers to the menu items which has the active or only passive elements inside (elemnts that are not clicked based on the url). 
In case someone has the same Problem ill provide more informationen on this.

Answer (score 1):

If this is intended as a menu you could build everything in an unordered list with list elements inside. Any nested menus can be done as such:

```html
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menuItem">
      <a href="#">Page 1</a>
      <ul class="subMenu">
        <li class="menuItem2"><a href="#">Sub Page 1</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem2"><a href="#">Sub Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem2"><a href="#">Sub Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

DOing it this way will allow you to target the :active list item that is built in with browsers. Then you could use css and jquery to make the dropdown magic. In jquery you can target the :active anchor as such:

```js
$('menu > li a:active').doSomething();
```

If this doesn't interest you, check out this other stack overflow answer that may be of help as well.

[Jquery - determining which link was clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903992/jquery-determining-which-link-was-clicked)

Cheers

Comment: I might not grab it, but i dont want to find out which linked was clicked. I wanna expand the menu according to what URL was visited in the first place.